# UNIQUE constraint failed: new__users_profile.user_id. Python Django

Tags: python, django

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError UNIQUE constraint failed 
>   sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: new__users_profile.user_id
>   The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>   new__users_profile.user_id

Error occurs when I'm trying to register new user, login to an existing user and when I am trying to migrate. I've tried to delete all migrations and migrate once again but it didn't help

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

class Media(models.Model):    
    image_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image_description = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    image_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media', default='default.jpg')
```

views

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from .forms import UserRegisterForm, MediaForm
from .models import Media


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created! You are now able to log in')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})


@login_required
def profile(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        media_images = Media.objects.all()


    context = {
        'media_images':media_images,

    }
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)

@login_required
def add_media(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MediaForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/')
    else:
        form = MediaForm()

    return render(request, 'users/add_media.html', {'form':form})
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import *

class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']

class MediaForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Media
        fields = ['image_name', 'image_description', 'image_image']
```

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Profile


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

Comment: You aim to create *two* profiles that refer to the *same* `User` object. A `OneToOneField` aims to prevent that.

Comment: Can you shouw the `UserRegisterForm`?

Comment: i added forms.py to the post

Comment: did you use signals to create a related `Profile` object?

Comment: yes im using signals. Added to a post

Comment: It looks like somehow you create a `Profile` multiple times. Perhaps due to multiple signals, multiple subscriptions to such signals, or because it is done in a form, etc. somewhere else as well.

Comment: yes I accidentally deleted the user object in Profile module, then i tried  to register a new user and then error occured and i realised that something is wrong, I added the missing user object but an error stil occurs

Comment: The data still might be in sql database. Have you tried deleting that as well?

Comment: I deleted database by using python manage.py flush and It WORKED. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

I think you need `primary_key=True,`

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

In class profile, add `primary_key=True` and remove `null=True`

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User,primary_key=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I hope it will work!